# Images changing as JComboBox selection changes and exporting as .JAR

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, getresource

I have my JLabel change as a JComboBox selection changes. I had originally used:

```
ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/image.png"));
```

and an action event which worked fine with the compiler. When I tried to export it as a .jar the files wouldn't load or switch. So I did some research and switched to using this method to get my pictures:

```
ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/images/image.png"));
```

Now when I try to switch the JComboBox selection the image does not change or appear. I have my images in an array as seen below.

```
final String[] images = {"birch_river.png", "elm_american.png", "maple_bigtooth.png", "oak_bur.png", "white_pine.png", "oak_willow.png"};
```

And here is the action:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) { 
        JComboBox treeSelectBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        int index = treeSelectBox.getSelectedIndex();
        //display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(images[index])));
        display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(tabbedTreeSafe.class.getResource(images[index])));
        descript.setText(treeDescription[index]);
        }
}
```

display is the JLabel where the images appear, and descript is just an array with a description of the image.

Comment: Where are the images stored?  Still in `images`?

Comment: yes resource folder called images

Comment: probably should've changed some names but the folder and the array are both called images

Comment: for ImageIcon2 or for setting the display.setIcon?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It worked for displaying the description, but still not the images

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `tabbedTreeSafe.class.getResource("/images/" + images[index])`